# Cutting down the size of a long blowfish key

Tags: encryption, keys, key-size, blowfish

I am reverse engineering a software that uses blowfish for encryption. The target uses an implementation of blowfish that allows arbitrary positive key length with a key size larger than 56 bytes.

I am looking for a way to cut the key size down to 56 bytes so that I can use a standard library to take care of the encryption instead of using a custom implementation like what the target did.

I started by cutting the key size to 72 bytes as I read [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25788/why-exactly-blowfish-max-key-length-is-448) that key bytes beyond the 72th have no effect. This 72-byte worked as a substitute for the original longer key.

Is there a way to cut the key further to 56 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *general* way yo use a function implementing Blowfish and enforcing its  maximum 56-byte key size, to emulate a function implementing a variant of Blowfish that does not enforce that limitation (which in practice means it uses up to 72 bytes of key). For most keys over 56 bytes, the plaintext/ciphertext mapping will be different; combining multiple calls won't help.

The only exceptions are keys which after truncation to 72-byte happen to be periodic with a period at most 56-byte. In that case, one can find the period, truncate the key to the period, and pass the truncated key to the function enforcing the maximum 56-byte key size. That works if the function supports the truncated key size, because Blowfish specifies that the key is used cyclically.

Example: key `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP`(64-byte) can be truncated to `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` (16-byte).

Note: If the minimal period of the actual key truncated to 72-byte is not supported (e.g. because the available Blowfish function enforces that the key length is a multiple of 4 bytes), but some multiple less than 56 is supported, then it is possible to use that multiple. Key `ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFxxxx` (76-byte with the first 72 of period 11) can be truncated to `ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFGHIJK` (44-byte).

<sup>But in anything like reverse-engineering or cryptanalysis, I can't understand why there would be the need to *"use a standard library to take care of the encryption instead of using a custom implementation"*. There should be the freedom of using a compiled language like C/C++ or Go, and then Blowfish is available in source form, that's little code, zapping its 56-byte limit is trivial, and such custom implementation can give the best speed by cutting down on interface.</sup>